# Solving simple functional relation

Tags: functional-equations

Satisfying  the boundary conditions

$$ y(0)=1, y(1)=2 $$

What general /particular functions obey
$$ 1) \quad y(x) \,y(x+1)= 2,$$

and

$$2)\quad \dfrac{y(x)}{y(x+1)}=\dfrac{1}{2}? \;$$

Comment: Is the function only defined on $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ or are you looking for functions defined on $\Bbb{R}$? In the latter case, what about continuity requirements?

Comment: New here, $\mathbb R$ smooth continuous fns for a start.

Comment: For 1) suppose $y>0$ and take $\log$, then distribute $\log 2$ from the RHS between two LHS terms, we end up with $f(x)+f(x+1)=0$ which have solutions e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1170708) (despite the RHS there is $x$, not a big problem, we can $g=f-\frac x2$)

Answer (score 0):

Although not explicitly mentioned in the OP, should we take 1) and 2) simultaneously or separately, taking this equations simultaneously don't make sense, as we have $\left(y(x)\right)^2=1$ after multiplying them, and this holds for any $x$, together with $y(1)=2$ makes a contradiction. So we consider 1) and 2) separately.

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1170757) after taking log of both parts we have
$$\hbox{1) }f(x)+f(x+1)=\ln 2\\
\hbox{2) }f(x)-f(x+1)=-\ln 2$$
First we homogenize it:
$$\hbox{1) }f(x)+f(x+1)=0\\
\hbox{2) }f(x)-f(x+1)=0$$
For the second it's clear that an arbitrary periodic function with the period $\frac{1}{n},\,n\in \mathbb{N}$ will do.

Then we set $f(x)=e^{i\pi x}g(x)$ for the first one:
$$e^{i\pi x}g(x)-e^{i\pi x}g(x+1)=0$$
So we have $f(x)=e^{i\pi x}g(x)$ for arbitrary periodic $g(x)$ with period of $\frac 1n$.

Now, as the particular solutions should be linear to have $f(0)=0,\,f(1)=\ln 2$ we're mostly done.

Answer:
$$\hbox{1) }y(x)=2^{x-1}\cdot e^{(e^{i\pi x})}\cdot g(x)\\
\hbox{2) }y(x)=2^{x-1}\cdot g(x)$$
for an arbitrary periodical function $g(x)$ with period $\frac 1n,\,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

And I'll add [Linear Difference and Functional Equations with One Independent Variable](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe-toc1.htm) for further reference if I have mistaken somewhere, that link could be of more help.

Comment: Yes, two different questions, numbered  differently.